# Querying jsonb column containing a json array with a single element

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

**I want to be able to use the same query syntax to return both rows**

Given a jsonb column, named 'tags' in a table called 'qux' with sample data in row 1:

```
{
  "foo": ["1","2"]
}
```

and row 2:

```
{
  "foo": ["3"]
}
```

and the pre-requisite index created on the column 'tags':

```
CREATE INDEX tag_idx ON tags USING GIN (tags);
```

When I run the following query:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM "qux" WHERE tags @> '{"foo": ["1"]}'
```

I expect to get a row back, which is correct.

If I run:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM "qux" WHERE tags @> '{"foo": ["3"]}'
```

I do not get any rows back, which feels unexpected. I can get the row back if I *remove the square brackets* on the second example, however that syntax breaks the first example.

Is this a known bug, or a problem with indexing? The version of postgres is 9.5

Comment: Works fine for me: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bsKnB5kBJAYuxDdW5bY83k/0 Obviously without indexes here. You could try reindexing if you feel that's where it's going wrong. Does running it via EXPLAIN ANALYZE show it using the index in that query?

Comment: I've added the index on db-fiddle and I'm indeed getting the correct response back. I'm wondering if there's something going wrong with psql (11.1 (Debian 11.1-1.pgdg90+1), server 9.5.14)

Comment: The index won't be used on db-fiddle because there's not enough data in there to warrant it. And even if it were an index issue, it wouldn't be recreateable there because the index would be in 100% condition, whereas on yours it possibly has a problem - so, assuming the query uses the jsonb index, try reindexing.